# ComboViewer in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a question. I am developing an Eclipse Plugin. I have got their some views.
My question is for two of them. 
The **View A (with the ComboViewer)** is reiceiver and sender as well.( This means the **View A** gets some some Values from another View, and the values are added into the ComboViewer of the **View A**.(This part i have realized), than this values are send to another **View B**.

**The code looks like as follows:**

public class ComboView extends ViewPart {

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(null);

    ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.NONE);
    Combo combo = comboViewer.getCombo();
    combo.setBounds(281, 163, 232, 22);
       BundleContext ctx = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(CommitView.class).getBundleContext();
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler() {
          public void handleEvent(final Event event) {

                if(SelectionView.viewwert!=0)
                {comboViewer.getCombo().removeAll();}
                else{

              if( parent.getDisplay().getThread() == Thread.currentThread() ) {
              comboViewer.add(event.getProperty("commidid"));
            } else {
              parent.getDisplay().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  comboViewer.add(event.getProperty("commidid"));
                }
              });
            }
                }
          }
        };

        Dictionary<String,String> properties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        properties.put(EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, "viewcommunicationcommidid/*");
        ctx.registerService(EventHandler.class, handler, properties);
      }

      @Override
      public void setFocus() {
      } 
}
```

When i execute my plugin then the values are shown in the ComboViewer of the **View A**

Now when i select a value of the Comboviewer in the **View A** Than this value will be compared with a database or an array, and the corresponding values should be shown in **view B**.And when i change value than it should be updated (This means it ahould be synchronous)

My Question is how can i get the seleceted value of the combobox, to work with this selection value.

I hope i could explain my problem.

Comment: A usual pattern to link views in the Eclipse workbench, is to use the [SelectionService](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html). Have tried this approach?

Comment: As an aside you need to learn about using [Layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). Using `setBounds` will fail as soon as the user chooses to use a different font

Comment: You are already listening for EventAdmin events from your source view, you could use the same event system to send to view B.